# Definite integral of polynomial times exponential times hypergeometric function of imaginary argument

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

How would one deal with such an integral?

$$I(k)\equiv \int_0^\infty r^n e^{-r(1+\mu)} e^{-{\mathrm i} kr}\:{}_1F_1({\mathrm i}/k+1;2;2{\mathrm i} kr) \, \mathrm{d} r$$

Here $n\in\{0,1\}$, $\mu\in \mathbb{R_0^+}$, $k>0$ is a real constant, $\;{}_1F_1$ is the confluent hypergeometric function (${\mathrm i}$ ist the imaginary unit).

Actually, if one tries with Mathematica, one gets a conditional expression with $\operatorname{Im}(k) > 0$ (see bbgodfrey's answer). If we assume $k$ to be real, Mathematica says that the integral does not converge, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78209/perturbation-theory-with-mathematica-definite-integral-of-polynomial-times-expo) post of mine (derived from this question) in the Mathematica forum.

But if we insert this integral into the following integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{k^2 e^{\pi/k}}{1+k^2}|\Gamma{(1-{\mathrm i}/k})|^2|I(k)|^2\mathrm{d} k,$$

the full double integral converges and Mathematica can handle it in less than one minute if numerical values of $n$ and $\mu$ are chosen. For n=1 and μ=0 it gives 0.0650882 (confirming the result of another perturbative method, see the motivation below). How to make sense of the behavior of the integrals and how to treat them correctly?

**Motivation - where does it come from?**

The integral arises from a problem in quantum mechanics. In more detail, it is the contribution of continuous states to second order correction to ground state energy (in the framework of Rayleigh-Schroedinger perturbation theory). The unperturbed system is the ground state of the hydrogen atom with radial function proportional to $R_0=e^{-r}$, the perturbation is the screened Coulomb potential (sometimes called the Yukawa potential) $H_p=e^{-\mu r}/r$. The expression for spherically symmetric continuous states of the hydrogen atom is $R_{k,l=0}(r)=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}k e^{\pi/2k} |\Gamma{(1-{\mathrm i}/k})| e^{-{\mathrm i} kr} {}_1F_1({\mathrm i}/k+1,2,2{\mathrm i} kr)$. Putting this into the expression for second order correction (from continuous states, apart from this, there is also the contribution from bound states):

$$E_0^{(2)}(continuum)= \int_0^\infty \frac{\left|\int_0^\infty r^2 R_0 H_p R_{k,l=0}\,\mathrm{d} r\right|^2}{E_0-E_k}\,\mathrm{d} k$$

gives the above integral (ground state energy $E_0=-1$, energy of continuous states $E_k=k^2$).

**Update:** see Jens' answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78320/22001

Comment: @Alex R. But the first term involves $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-n r}}{r}dr$ which is divergent.

Comment: Alex R. claimed to express $_1F_1(i/k+1;2;2i kr)$ as power series form and integrate termwisely.

Comment: Can you include a bit more detail on the QM problem which motivates this question? That could help us to see what approaches are most likely to bear fruit.

Comment: You have $n$ in two places, are they the same?  (I wonder because you say that $n\in\{0,1\}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$; which is it?)

Comment: My *Mathematica* fails to evaluate $I(k)$, given your assumptions for the parameters. It does not evaluate even with $n=\mu=0$. Are you sure this worked?

Comment: @wondering: Which $l$ are you talking about? There is none in your formulae.

Comment: Question corrected & motivation added. An important observation in the answer of bbgodfrey.

Comment: In the interest of housekeeping, could please clarify what parts of the problem you still need answered?

Comment: @DavidH Well, Jens' answer mentioned in the update can be regarded as an answer to this post, too. It's more complete than bbgodrey's answer below. I think a solution could be to mark bbgodrey's post as an answer and mention Jens' answer in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no conditions applied to the parameters, Mathematica gives for the integral,

```
((-I)*k)^(-1 - n)*(-(k/(k - I*(1 + mu))))^(1 + n)*Gamma[1 + n]*
 Hypergeometric2F1[(I + k)/k, 1 + n, 2, (2*k)/(k - I*(1 + mu))]
```

but as part of a `ConditionalExpresson` with conditions that are not satisfied for `k` real.  Nonetheless, the expression seems well behaved there and gives the same numerical results as sample numerical integrations.

Comment: For future visitors: see also Jens' answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78320/22001